# Is it possible to virtualize Android on an X86 machine?

Tags: lineageos, virtualbox, virtualization

Following [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/j9zvs1/is_it_possible_to_virtualize_lineageos_on_a/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I had [a little bit of success](https://www.reddit.com/r/BlissOS/comments/hq6nus/does_anyone_have_a_tutorial_for_emulating_bliss/g8mytdv?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) installing an X86 port of Android (i.e., BlissOS) on macOS with QEMU. Now I am wondering if I can virtualize a "normal" Android (preferably LineageOS) on any of the conventional FLOSS hypervisors such as VirtualBox, QEMU... (preferably something portable on Windows).

There are `qemu-system-arm` and `qemu-system-aarch64` versions of QEMU that I expect to do the job. Over [here](https://www.linaro.org/blog/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/), [Alex Bennée](https://twitter.com/stsquad) is doing some magic with the so-called "ranchu kernel" that I can't really understand and trust. Meanwhile, on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539867/4999991) it's being said that the upstream QEMU hasn't inherited the graphic acceleration back from Google's Android Studio Emulator.

Now my questions are:

1. what is that "ranchu kernel"? and how much it can be trusted?
2. Can I virtualize LineageOS or any other well-known FLOSS Android? How?

Comment: Could [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/6892/185) on our sister site for Software Recommendations be what you are looking for? It's a bit "dusty", don't let the "Android 4.3" scare you away – 6 years later, there are newer versions available as well, of course. A longer list of candidates can be found at the end of [this page](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/emulators) (on my Android website).